# skinning view in flex mobile to add background: is that a bug?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I added a background to my views in flex mobile.

I just realized that if I do not include that line:

```
<s:Group id="contentGroup" width="100%" height="100%" minWidth="0" minHeight="0"/>
```

only my image is shown and I cannot show anything else.
The very strange thing is that I used :

new-mxml skin
and host component: **spark.components.View**

and the wizzard did not add this crucial line (I have found that on samples):

```
<s:Group id="contentGroup" width="100%" height="100%" minWidth="0" minHeight="0"/>
```

1) Is that a bug ? or is there another simpler way do that ?

2) to avoid others bugs like this one, is there some good practises to skin other components ? (using catalyst ? using fireworks ?)

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that a bug ? or is there another simpler way do that ?

No, that's not a bug.  The skin for a `View` class has "skin part" named `contentGroup`, and this is the object that the `View` component uses to display its child components.  Without this skin part, your view has no container to hold the child components.

Every component that has a skin defines a set of "skin parts". Some skin parts are required, others are not.

Strangely enough, the `contentGroup` skin part is not required, though it's pretty useless to exclude it.

> To avoid others bugs like this one, is there some good practises to skin other components ?

The best practice is to look at the documentation to see what skin parts a component declares. For example, [here is a link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/View.html#SkinPartSummary) to the "skin parts" section of the docs for the `View` component. On the top right of every page in the docs, there is a "skin parts" link to jump to this section of the page.

When you use the wizard to create an MXML Skin, you have an option to copy the code from one of the existing skins that Flex defines. If you do this, you will get some code that includes all of the skin parts and a bunch of Adobe styling code.

If you do not copy the original skin, you get an empty MXML skin. However, the wizard will create a comment in the the code telling you what the skin parts are, and if they're required or not.  Here's the comment you get when creating an empty `View` skin:

```
<!-- SkinParts
name=contentGroup, type=spark.components.Group, required=false
-->
```

You can use other tools like Catalyst, but they're not necessary (I believe Catalyst has been discontinued anyway). Sometimes I start by creating the skin w/Adobe's default code and stripping away what I don't want. Other times there's so much "clutter", I just use a blank skin.